# Virsh hangs while trying to connect

Tags: libvirt

Running this command:

```
# virsh -c qemu:///system list
```

As root user, hangs with no error message. Not sure what's causing this. This problem started after a power failure in my lab. When I brought the hypervisor server up (Oracle Linux 6.3, 2.6.39-300.17.3.el6uek.x86_64) I had to reconfigure the network because the device names (eth4 -> eth0) changed and network config reverted to dhcp for some strange reason. Even after resolving this, it virsh hangs with no error message.

Where should I be looking with regard to troubleshooting?

Comment: Have you tried to `ltrace` or `strace` it?  `sudo ltrace virsh -c qemu://system list`. Do you see perhaps any missing library when you run `ldd $(type -P virsh)` ?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this in future, I was having the problem of "virsh" hanging under root and virt-manager not connecting to "QEMU/KVM"  (i.e. showing "connecting..." and not connecting to qemu:///system sucessfully) when started up / running.

Using `sudo systemctl restart libvirtd` while the hang is in progress transiently fixes the issue until a system reboot for me